# Convert multiple appends values into panda dataframe using python

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, date, append

Here I have some append values with date. I want to convert these data into pandas. But I don't know how to do it.

Here's my code to read append value:
before this code I wrote another code to append the value. After that I want to read 4 values as four column wise.

```
x1.append({'date':next_record_time, 'x1':new_x1)
x2.append({'date':next_record_time, 'x2':new_x2})
x3.append({'date':next_record_time, 'x3':new_x3})
x4.append({'date':next_record_time, 'x4':new_x4})
pd.DataFrame(x1, columns=['date', 'x1'])
```

then value

```html
    date                              x1
2018-06-08 09:15:00    500                             
2018-06-08 10:15:00    812.0015321149272
2018-06-08 11:15:00    1256.691444199051
2018-06-08 12:15:00    784.1793119716488
2018-06-08 13:15:00    489.3302935759677
2018-06-08 14:15:00    805.343602611898
2018-06-08 15:15:00    502.5368757877344

    date                               x2
2018-06-08 15:00:00    2
2018-06-08 16:00:00    1.8711387084858075
2018-06-08 17:00:00    1.7505800331969679
2018-06-08 18:00:00    1.6377890312086083
2018-06-08 19:00:00    1.5322652263139487
2018-06-08 20:00:00    1.4335403883113977
2018-06-08 21:00:00    1.3411764553736159

  date                               x3
2018-06-08 09:16:00    50
2018-06-08 10:16:00    35.357940964363564
2018-06-08 11:16:00    25.003679784788382
2018-06-08 12:16:00    17.681572674447967
2018-06-08 13:16:00    12.503680055604704
2018-06-08 14:16:00    58.842087624867226
2018-06-08 15:16:00    41.61070120919926

     date                             x4
2018-06-08 09:15:00    40
2018-06-08 10:15:00    37.75543557660705
2018-06-08 11:15:00    35.63682288948313
2018-06-08 12:15:00    33.63709426897089
2018-06-08 13:15:00    31.749578641409713
2018-06-08 14:15:00    29.967979274504085
2018-06-08 15:15:00    28.286352771490854
```

As you can see this is my four append value

Then what I need is to insert all dates in one column and read x1,x2,x3,x4 as four columns .What I expected output is:

```html
date                    x1                     x2             x3            x4
2018-06-08 09:15:00     500                     0              0            40
2018-06-08 09:16:00      0                      0              50            0  
2018-06-08 10:15:00   812.0015321149272         0              0            37.75543557660705 
2018-06-08 10:16:00      0                      0        35.357940964363564  0 
2018-06-08 11:15:00   1256.691444199051         0              0            35.63682288948313
2018-06-08 11:16:00      0                      0        25.003679784788382  0   
2018-06-08 12:15:00   784.1793119716488         0              0             33.63709426897089
2018-06-08 12:16:00      0                      0        17.681572674447967  0
2018-06-08 13:15:00   489.3302935759677         0              0             31.74957864140971
2018-06-08 13:16:00      0                      0        12.503680055604704  0
2018-06-08 14:15:00   805.343602611898          0              0             29.967979274504085
2018-06-08 14:16:00      0                      0        58.842087624867226  0
2018-06-08 15:00:00      0                      2             0              0
2018-06-08 15:15:00   502.5368757877344         0             0         28.286352771490854
2018-06-08 15:16:00      0                      0        1.8711387084858075  0
```

I got only one data values after converting into pandas.
Here's what I got:

```html
         date               x1
0  2018-06-08 09:15:00  40.000000
1  2018-06-08 10:15:00  37.755436
2  2018-06-08 11:15:00  35.636823
3  2018-06-08 12:15:00  33.637094
4  2018-06-08 13:15:00  31.749579
5  2018-06-08 14:15:00  29.967979
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC,

first, pass all your dictionaries into a list then we read them as a single data frame we can then melt and stack your columns to get your desired result.

```
data_dicts = x1 + x2 + x3 + x4

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dicts)
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)

s = pd.melt(df,id_vars='date')
final = s.groupby(['date','variable'])['value'].first().unstack().reset_index().fillna(0)
del final.columns.name
```

#### Result :

```
print(final)

                  date           x1        x2         x3         x4
0  2018-06-08 09:15:00   500.000000  0.000000   0.000000  40.000000
1  2018-06-08 09:16:00     0.000000  0.000000  50.000000   0.000000
2  2018-06-08 10:15:00   812.001532  0.000000   0.000000  37.755436
3  2018-06-08 10:16:00     0.000000  0.000000  35.357941   0.000000
4  2018-06-08 11:15:00  1256.691444  0.000000   0.000000  35.636823
5  2018-06-08 11:16:00     0.000000  0.000000  25.003680   0.000000
6  2018-06-08 12:15:00   784.179312  0.000000   0.000000  33.637094
7  2018-06-08 12:16:00     0.000000  0.000000  17.681573   0.000000
8  2018-06-08 13:15:00   489.330294  0.000000   0.000000  31.749579
9  2018-06-08 13:16:00     0.000000  0.000000  12.503680   0.000000
10 2018-06-08 14:15:00   805.343603  0.000000   0.000000  29.967979
11 2018-06-08 14:16:00     0.000000  0.000000  58.842088   0.000000
12 2018-06-08 15:00:00     0.000000  2.000000   0.000000   0.000000
13 2018-06-08 15:15:00   502.536876  0.000000   0.000000  28.286353
14 2018-06-08 15:16:00     0.000000  0.000000  41.610701   0.000000
15 2018-06-08 16:00:00     0.000000  1.871139   0.000000   0.000000
16 2018-06-08 17:00:00     0.000000  1.750580   0.000000   0.000000
17 2018-06-08 18:00:00     0.000000  1.637789   0.000000   0.000000
18 2018-06-08 19:00:00     0.000000  1.532265   0.000000   0.000000
19 2018-06-08 20:00:00     0.000000  1.433540   0.000000   0.000000
20 2018-06-08 21:00:00     0.000000  1.341176   0.000000   0.000000
```